# ImportError: No module named PIL, even though module seems to be installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, python-imaging-library

When trying to import the PIL module, which I previously pip-installed, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/user1/Desktop/script.py", line 94, in <module>
   from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

My script is run in /usr/local/bin/python3 the modules are saved at /usr/local/bin/pip3. When typing pip3 list in the terminal, "Pillow" also seems to exist. 
Is there a way to fix the error? What could have caused it ?

relevant part of code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# !/usr/local/bin/python3

import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
```

Comment: Try running `python3 -m pip install …` instead of `pip3 install …`. Could be they’re using different paths for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I tried it but the paths seem to be the same: "Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (7.0.0)"

Comment: The problem does not occur if I execute the script through terminal instead of VS-code. > The issue is somewhere within Visual  Studio Code.

Comment: How do you run your file? Is it `python3 myfile.py` or just `./myfile.py`? The wrong interpreter could be used if shebang string is not the first line in your script. Also there shouldn’t be spaces between # and !

Comment: In VSCode you can press Cmd+Shift+P and search for “select python interpreter” command.

Comment: Thanks, running it with python3 myfile.py does work, but ./myfile.py does somehow not work (Permission denied). Also, after I deleted the space inbetween the # and !, the error with VS-code seemed to be resolved. Thnak you!